# MongoDB replication on all nodes: status?

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongodb-.net-driver

Here is my question:
I would like to use MongoDB replica capabilities to provide a read-only replica set of data to be pushed to devices.

My problem right now is that I would like to know when certain documents are inserted/updated AND replicated accross all nodes.

As I an sending notifications on top, I would like to make sure this data is updated before sending them.

Comment: How many devices do you have?  Replicasets have a hard limit of 12 members at the moment ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#replica-sets )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by specifying tags for the read members and providing a custom write concern for the insert/update operations so that they will only return after the operation has completed and been replicated to the tagged nodes you care about.

You can read more about it here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/#custom-write-concerns

Comment: Is there a way once write concerns are overriden to make writes only to return also using C# driver ?

Answer (score 0):

First to make sure your data is in synch across secondaries you have to set appropriate write concerns when insertig/updating
[Write concern docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/)

Then to see if data was inserted/updated you have to monitor the replica primary oplog file 
[Replica Oplog docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/)

Note I believe you can state that your replica set is consistent when all the members have roughly the same oplog files.